# Sum of multiples of powers of ten of an integer

Tags: code-golf, integer

Write a function to produce, for a non-negative integer, a string containing a sum of terms according to the following:

```
3 -> "3"

805 -> "800 + 5"

700390 -> "700000 + 300 + 90"

0 -> "0"

13 -> "10 + 3"

200 -> "200"
```

Any input other than a non-negative integer can be ignored. Zero terms must be skipped unless the input is 0. Terms must go from largest to smallest. The plus signs must have only a single space on either side.

This is code golf; fewest number of bytes wins.

Comment: The edge case of an input of zero seems awkward and yet easily avoidable with "for a *positive* integer...".

Comment: Thank you so much for detecting the inconsistency. Regarding the +, I'd like to see how people can golf the join, so it was intentional. I say "nonnegative" instead of "positive" on purpose as well. Nonnegative includes 0 which will indeed make the code longer and IMHO more of a challenge to golf. It's true that a list of positive integers (filtered to remove zeros) is way easier, but I did add the two complications as a challenge. I don't use this site too often so if these kinds of complications are frowned upon please let me know for sure. Thanks.

Comment: ...not really frowned upon, just seems like the core of the challenge on its own would make for a better question. Are the single spaces required or optional?

Comment: Required. Though I think I have an idea of how to ask next time. :) Cheers :)

Comment: Flexibile output format is generally preferred

Comment: Thanks good to know. For next time.

Comment: Subset of [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68939/76162). Enough so, that I would consider this a dupe

Comment: Didn't see that. Should I delete? Okay if anyone wants to close it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
DḊƬḌINḟ0ȯ0j”+K
```

A full program which prints the result

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//ROG4isas4biMSU7huJ8wyK8wauKAnStL////NzAwMzkwIA)**

#### How?

```
DḊƬḌINḟ0ȯ0j”+K - Main Link: integer, n       e.g. 805
D              - to base ten                      [8,0,5]
  Ƭ            - collect until a fixed point:
 Ḋ             -   dequeue                        [[8,0,5],[0,5],[5],[]]
   Ḍ           - from base ten (vectorises)       [ 805,    5,    5,  0]
    I          - incremental differences          [    -800,   0,   -5 ]
     N         - negate                           [     800,   0,    5 ]
      ḟ0       - filter discard zeros             [     800,         5 ]
        ȯ0     - OR zero (replacing an empty list with 0)
          j”+  - join with '+' characters         [     800,  '+',   5 ]
             K - join with space characters       [800,' ','+',' ',5]
               - implicit, smashing print         "800 + 5"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 31 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function, taking the number as a string.

```apl
(1↓∘∊1@1∘×⊆⌽∘⍳∘≢('+',10⊥↑)¨⊢)⍎¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X8PwUdvkRx0zHnV0GToYAhmHpz/qanvUsxck1rsZRHYu0lDXVtcxNHjUtfRR20TNQysedS3SfNTbd2jF/7RHbROArEd9Uz39H3U1H1pvDFQB5AUHOQPJEA/P4P9pOurG6lxp6hYGpiDK3MDA2NIAyNJRB5HqhmBJIwMDdQA)

`⍎¨` execute each character (this gives the digits as numbers)

`(`…`)` apply the following anonymous tacit prefix function to that:

…`(`…`)¨⊢` apply the below function between each element and the corresponding element of…

`⌽` the reversal
 `∘` of
 `⍳` the **ɩ**ndices (1…N)
 `∘` of
 `≢` the tally of digits

`↑` take that many elements, padding with zeros (as there's only ever one)

`10⊥` evaluate that in base ten

`'+',` prepend a plus

…`⊆` partition it beginning a new segment where indicated by:

`1@1` a one **at** the first element
 `∘` of
 `×` the sign (0 for 0; 1 for all other)

`1↓` drop the first
`∘` of
`∊` the **ϵ**nlisted (flattened) data

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 53 bytes

```perl
$&&&push@a,$&.y//0/cr while s/.//;$"=" + ";$_="@a"||0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcvRCsIgFADQd7/iYiJFbd41RoUM9gN9Q8gSNGzKvCOCfXu2t/Nykp1DV4qQUqYlu8GchKy/SqEaZ/g4HyxkVSulBe85HIFr8ej5YPi6YtGD6fcHvXstmcDZ2QJFcGZ6buu9BPJpA9lMGQxBnEZbWnbFjl0Q2xsyZE3Lzoi/mMjHKZfq3tXYYKlS@AM)